# using arabic words in pdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, arabic

I am trying to generate pdf in arabic but words are not rendered properly in pdf ,I am using php script built on fpdf
to generate invoice in pdf format which not working properly ,it is working properly using english words
what i have tried: - download a font which support Arabic letters
below is my code

```
require('mysql_table.php');
// $name="";
$pid=$_GET['invoice'];
  $np=$_SESSION['net_amountt'];

class PDF extends PDF_MySQL_Table
{
function Header()
{ $name=$_SESSION['admin'];
$d=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    //Title
    $this->AddFont('Cairo-Regular', 'B', 'Cairo-Regular.php');
    $this->SetFont('Cairo-Regular','',18);
    $this->Cell(0,6,'الفاتورة',0,1,'C');
        $this->Cell(0,1,"$d",0,1,'R');
        $this->Cell(0,1,"الاسم:$name",0,1,'L');
    $this->Ln(10);
    //Ensure table header is output
    parent::Header();
}
}



//Connect to database
// mysql_connect('localhost','root','35437411');
// mysql_select_db('egrocery');




$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->AddFont('Cairo-Regular', '', 'Cairo-Regular.php');

$pdf->AddPage();
//First table: put all columns automatically
//$pdf->Table('select * from order_detail where customer_id="'.$pid.'"');
//$pdf->AddPage();
//Second table: specify 3 columns
//$pdf->AddCol('id',20,'','C');
$pdf->AddCol('المنتج',40,'product');
$pdf->AddCol('السعر',40,'price','R');
$pdf->AddCol('الكمية',20,'Quantity','R');
$prop=array('HeaderColor'=>array(100,150,100),
            'color1'=>array(210,245,255),
            'color2'=>array(255,255,210),
            'padding'=>2);
//calling stored procedure for fetchng order detail of user
$stp='call order_details("fetch","","","",'.$pid.',"")';

$pdf->Table($stp,$prop);


$con= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=egrocery","root","35437411");
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
//calling stored procedure for fetchng total amount of user
$stp1="call payment(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$evnt="fetch_total";
$a="";

//$st=$con->prepare('SELECT SUM(payment.total_payment)as Total_Amount FROM payment WHERE payment.customer_id='.$pid.'');
$st=$con->prepare($stp1);
$st->bindParam(1, $evnt);
$st->bindParam(2, $pid);
$st->bindParam(3, $a);
$st->bindParam(4, $a);
$st->bindParam(5, $a);
$st->bindParam(6, $a);
$st->bindParam(7, $a);
$st->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$st->execute();
    
$pdf->Ln(11);
$fontPath = constant("FPDF_FONTPATH");

$pdf->SetFont('Cairo-Regular','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,"القيمة الاجمالية".$st->fetchColumn()."",0,1,'C');
$pdf->Output();
```

this is a screenshot of the pdf output :
[image]

Comment: Arabic is not supported.

Comment: @Olivier is there any workaround for that problem

Comment: You can try TCPDF.

Comment: I tried using it, it returns the same error